# In SOAP, is it possible for a function to return different data types?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I need to build a SOAP webservice that host a function that, in a specific scenario, it will return for example an object of type Object1 and in another scenario, the same function will return an object but of type Object2. Is it possible to do that? And if so, how will I write that in the WSDL file? At this point, I have the following syntax:

```
<wsdl:message name = "MyFunctionRequest">
  <wsdl:part name = "MyFunctionParameter" type = "xsd:int"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name = "MyFunctionResponse">
  <wsdl:part name = "MyFunctionReturnParameter" type = "tns:Object1"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name = "MyFunctionPortType">
  <wsdl:operation name = "MyFunctionOperationName">
    <wsdl:input message = "tns:MyFunctionRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message = "tns:MyFunctionResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Is there a way to say something like:

```
<wsdl:part name = "MyFunctionReturnParameter" type = "tns:Object1|tns:Object2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one result.

But you can make that an element that contains an <xsd:choice>.

```
<xsd:choice>
   <xsd:element name="one" ... />
   <xsd:element name="orTheOther" ... />
</xsd:choice>
```

You could [search for some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Awsdl%20%22choice%22).

Do note however that some SOAP clients might have challenges with this. Normally, when yo generate a client, based on the elements in the WSDL, your tool of choice generates types. And with a <xsd:choice> that could mean two or more unrelated types. You will probably get a generic type of something like "Object" in the signature of the method/function, and then you have to check which object type it is within the method/function. Makes it a bit awkward to work with.